# Module build failed: Unknown word (2:9) | Problem with bundle/webpack (react, redux, js, node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, redux

**Problem:**

I've looked everywhere for someone with a similar problem and had a busy person also kindly spend some time trying to help me, but I'm not finding docs or other resources very helpful, has anyone else had this issue?

This is whats happened so far:

I firstly get the error whenI was trying to import a css style like so,

`import 'react-day-picker/lib/style.css'`

the error being:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-day-picker/lib/style.css Module parse
     failed: Unexpected token (3:0) You may need an appropriate loader 
     to handle this file type. | /* DayPicker styles */ | | .DayPicker { |  
     display: inline-block; |   font-size: 1rem;  @
     ./client/components/Component.jsx 21:0-41  @
     ./client/components/App.jsx  @ ./client/index.js
```

So I have added a css-loader and updated my webpack as well to try fix this issue but I still get:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader!./client/index.js
Module build failed: Unknown word (2:9)

 1 | import React from 'react'
> 2 | import {render} from 'react-dom'
    |         ^
  3 | import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
  4 | import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux'
  5 | import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'

 @ ./client/index.js 3:14-73
```

Please Help! Below are my files.

---

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, '/index.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../server/public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
      rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: ['babel-loader', 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
      }
    })
  ],
  devtool: 'source-map'
}
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^6.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-jwt": "^5.3.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "knex": "^0.14.4",
    "leaflet": "^1.3.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "pg": "^7.4.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react": "^16.1.1",
    "react-day-picker": "^7.2.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.1.1",
    "react-geocode": "^0.1.2",
    "react-leaflet": "^1.9.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "sodium": "^2.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "superagent": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack": "^4.17.1",
    "webpack-command": "^0.4.1"

  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.2.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.0",
    "jest": "^21.1.0",
    "jsdom": "^11.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
    "sqlite3": "^3.1.9",
    "supertest": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.7"
  }
}
```

---

**Solution:**

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, '/index.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../server/public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
      rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: ['babel-loader'],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
    }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
      }
    })
  ],
  devtool: 'source-map'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css file loader needs to be separate from jsx file loader.

Resolve loader to import a css file in your config:

```
    module.exports = {
      module: {
         rules: [
          {
              test: /\.css$/,
              use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
          }
         ]
        }
       }
```

Comment: Oh whoops, I did have it like that previously on `webpack v3`  - so maybe doing it this way on the new version is better and with a different css file being imported helped it also. This fixed it though thank you!
Edit: Before I was using react-dates which required a few other packages too, this fix worked using a new dates package react-day-picker :) (For anyone seeking this answer)

Comment: Hmm, I've always setup my loaders separately, did not know you could do them together... but anywho, glad it works!